# custom scrollbar using javascript with no plugins

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a custom scrollbar using javascript. I have following jsfiddle code

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uq2pLufn/)

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

It currently has browser's default scrollbar but I want to implement my own with pure javascript. I know there are css3 solutions available but it has browser compatibility issues. There are also plenty of jquery plugins available but my requirement is only javascript.

**How can I implement this?**

Comment: you know, quick clarification: when you say no plugins, do you mean no frameworks like jquery, or do you mean no pre-made plugins?

Answer (score 4):

This is just an quick example. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uq2pLufn/3/) here. Please check.

TODO:

1. Add listener to key event, like up arrow, down arrow and space
2. Add listener to mouse scroll event.
3. Drag and drop event on scroll anchor.
4. Touch event (if touch devices needed to be supported).

Hope this is useful.

**UPDATE**

Remove jQuery. Got a mistake, didn't read the question very carefully.

```js
var scrollBarContainer = document.getElementById('scroll');
var anchor = document.getElementById('anchor');
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var content = document.querySelectorAll('#container > *:not(#scroll)');

var containerHeight = container.offsetHeight;
var contentHeight = 0;
console.log(content);
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  contentHeight += content[i].scrollHeight;
}

anchor.style.height = Math.floor(containerHeight / contentHeight * containerHeight) + 'px';

var flag_mouseDown = false;
var oldMousePosition = 0;
var oldAnchorPosition = 0;
scrollBarContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'DIV') {
    var distance = e.clientY - container.offsetTop - anchor.offsetHeight / 2;
    if (distance < 0) {
      distance = 0;
    } else if (distance + anchor.offsetHeight > containerHeight) {
      distance = containerHeight - anchor.offsetHeight;
    }
    anchor.style.top = distance + 'px';
    moveContent();
  } else if (e.target.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
    flag_mouseDown = true;
    oldMousePosition = e.clientY;
    oldAnchorPosition = anchor.offsetTop;
  }
});
scrollBarContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  flag_mouseDown = false;
  oldMousePosition = e.clientY;
  oldAnchorPosition = anchor.offsetTop;
});
scrollBarContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (!flag_mouseDown) {
    return;
  }

  var distance = e.clientY - oldMousePosition;
  var newPosition = oldAnchorPosition + distance;

  if (newPosition < 0) {
    newPosition = 0;
  } else if (newPosition + anchor.offsetHeight > containerHeight) {
    newPosition = containerHeight - anchor.offsetHeight;
  }
  anchor.style.top = newPosition + 'px';
  moveContent();
});

var moveContent = function() {
  var postion = anchor.offsetTop / (containerHeight - anchor.offsetHeight);
  var newPosition = (0 - postion * (contentHeight - containerHeight)) + 'px';
  console.log(anchor.offsetTop, container.offsetTop, containerHeight, anchor.offsetHeight);
  console.log(postion, contentHeight, containerHeight);
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    content[i].style.marginTop = newPosition;
  }
};
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 17px;
}
#scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 17px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
  background-color: #eee;
}
#anchor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 17px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
#anchor:hover,
#anchor:active {
  background-color: #333;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="scroll">
    <span id="anchor"></span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```